# Can't get image2 plugin working with ckeditor version 4.7

Tags: ckeditor

I have installed the image2 plugin (along with the supporting widget, widgetselections and lineutils plugins) and updated config.extraPlugins accordingly. I am getting the following error on the page that instantiates ckeditor:

Uncaught TypeError: editor.plugins.detectConflict is not a function

I can't find that function call in the ckeditor codebase.

Has anyone come across this before?

Thanks in advance!